# Problema al importar método de otra clase

Tags: android, clase, java-8, método

Intento implementar un método en otra clase y me salta un error en ejecución:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

Esta es la clase donde creo el método

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class showpublicidad extends AppCompatActivity {

InterstitialAd interstitialAd; 


public void showpublicidad () {
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd (this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8842170315775506/2741588618");
    AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest1);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener () {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            interstitialAd.show();  } });}
}
```

Aquí donde intente implementarlo y al cargar esta actividad se para la aplicación.

```
public class prueba extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.terminos_uso );

    showpublicidad mostrarPublicidad = new showpublicidad ();
    mostrarPublicidad.showpublicidad ();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que al crear la instancia de la clase de `showpublicidad`, no te la está cogiendo bien.

En el caso de que importaras la clase arriba, podrías hacer referencia a la función si necesidad de crear una instancia.

```
import ruta.de.tu.clase.showpublicidad;
public class prueba extends AppCompatActivity {

  InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
      setContentView ( R.layout.terminos_uso );

      showpublicidad.showpublicidad(this);
   }
}
```

Vamos a intentar pasandole el contexto de la actividad que este activa.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class showpublicidad extends AppCompatActivity {

InterstitialAd interstitialAd; 


public void showpublicidad (Context contexto) {
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd (contexto);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8842170315775506/2741588618");
    AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest1);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener () {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            interstitialAd.show();  } });}
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo Iñigo me dige que no puede usarse un metodo no estatica, referenciando de forma estatica.

Comment: Si, tienes que hacer que el método de showpublicidad sea estático: public static void showpublicidad ()

Comment: Ahora el error esta en el contexto this----> interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd (this);

Comment: claro, porque la variable interstitialAd  está en la activity de showpublicidad el this hace referencia a la otra actividad que no está activa. Además esa variable se debe de inicializar en el mñetodo onCreate().

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, ¿Que modifico en el código para solucionarlo?

Comment: Yo lo dejaría así, porque no entiendo muy bien el porque lo sacas a otra clase.

Comment: Porque tendria el mísmo método en todas las clases en las que quiero mostrar publicidad en la app. Creo que sería más cómodo llamar a ese método cuando quiero que se muestre que crearlo en todas las actividades.

Comment: Creo que esto último te debería de quitar e,error del this.

Comment: SOLUCIONADO!!! Muchas gracias por tiempo y ayuda Iñigo.

Comment: De nada, ha sido un placer